# How do over-achievers and/or professional athletes overcome summit syndrome?

Tags: sports-psychology

HBR covers the syndrome [here](http://blogs.hbr.org/2014/09/the-unexpected-consequences-of-success/) and [here](http://hbr.org/2007/03/crisis-at-the-summit/ar/1). I have experienced this in some many different areas such as football: what do you need to do next when you have achieved everything you wanted? To become better, you need so much more investment such as time, new shoes, advanced training partners, better understand nutrition and trade-offs (no time for friends etc).

**How do professionals overcome the the summit syndrome in Sports?**